# SQL NOT IN Query on MS ACCESS/VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the following Course table with different extract dates.

```
ID | Course | ExtractDate
10 | 100000 | 2017-02-28
10 | 100001 | 2017-01-31
10 | 100002 | 2016-12-31
10 | 100003 | 2016-11-30
```

I need to perform the following SQL script to keep only records from the latest 3 months, and hence removing the record with Course code 10003.

```
Delete from [Course] where [ExtractDate] not in (select distinct top 3 [ExtractDate] from [Course] order by [ExtractDate] desc
```

Seems like VBA or MS Access does not support the function "not in", anybody has any workaround for this?

Thank you.

Comment: is it really the last 3 months?  you could just delete records with dates that are older.  That would be faster too.  take a look at the dateadd function (hint, a minus value will subtract)

Comment: Access SQL happily supports `NOT IN`. Your problem is that you use `distinct`  and `top` together, which is according to Access SQL is not allowed:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177882(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: in fact i have tried the 2 following before but they do not work.  (1) Delete from [Course] Where DateAdd(‘m’, 3, ExtractDate) < Now()
(2) Delete from [Course] Where DateDiff(‘m’, ExtractDate, now()) > 3

Comment: Access wants you to write `DELETE * FROM...`

Comment: i doubt the * will make any difference in MS ACCESS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want records older than three months:

```
Delete from [Course]
    where [ExtractDate] < dateadd("m", -3, date());
```

No set-based operation is needed.

Comment: i just tried, it doesn't seems to be working. the unwanted records are not being deleted. it is working fine on SQL server though. I am thinking whether its the DATEADD / DATEDIFF function that is not supported by MS ACCESS 2016.

Comment: @user1688194 . . . `dateadd()` is definitely in MS Access (https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php).

Comment: Oh no, there was a stupid mistake that i have made which cause the records to not be deleted. It is working now already. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

NOT IN is the same as a left join where the target is null (thus there was no join)

SO...

```
from [Course]
where [ExtractDate] not in (
   select distinct top 3 [ExtractDate] 
   from [Course] 
   order by [ExtractDate] desc
)
```

is the same as

```
from [Course]
left join (
   select distinct top 3 [ExtractDate] 
   from [Course] 
   order by [ExtractDate] desc
) as x on [ExtractDate] = x.[ExtractDate]
where x.[ExtractDate] is null
```

However, I make no claim any of your code was correct -- just that those two are the same in SQL.

Comment: this will work if it is a select statement. but i need to delete those records that fall under the condition.